# Getting YouTube to appear after cover is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

How it should work is:

After it is clicked, YouTube should appear on the screen, but it is not.

What needs to be fixed/adjusted in the code for that to occur?

Also, I keeping getting an error message for some reason.

It is asking me to provide more info but that is all.

code https://jsfiddle.net/rsbwe91z/

```js
const load = (function () {
   "use strict";

   function _load(tag) {
      return function (url) {
         return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            const element = document.createElement(tag);
            const parent = "body";
            const attr = "src";
            element.onload = function () {
               resolve(url);
            };
            element[attr] = url;
            document[parent].appendChild(element);
         });
      };
   }
   return {
      js: _load("script")
   };
}());

(function manageCover() {
   "use strict";

   function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
      document.querySelector(".curtain").classList.add("slide");
   }

   function hide(el) {
      el.classList.add("hide");
   }

   function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const thewrap = cover.parentNode.querySelector(".container");
      hide(cover);
      show(thewrap);

   }
   const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
   cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
   "use strict";

   function onPlayerReady(event) {
      const player = event.target;
      player.setVolume(100); // percent
   }
   let hasShuffled = false;

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      const player = event.target;
      const shufflePlaylist = true;

      if (!hasShuffled) {
         player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
         player.playVideoAt(0);
         hasShuffled = true;
      }
   }

   function addVideo(video) {

      const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";

      new YT.Player(video, {

         width: 640,
         height: 360,
         host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
         playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            controls: 1,
            loop: 1,
            rel: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            fs: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
            playlist
         },
         events: {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
         }
      });
   }

   function init(opts) {
      load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function () {
         YT.ready(function () {
            addVideo(opts.video);
         });
      });
   }
   return {
      init
   };
}());

(function iife() {
   "use strict";

   function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
   }

   function initPlayer(wrapper) {
      videoPlayer.init({
         video: wrapper.querySelector(".video")
      });
   }

   function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      initPlayer(wrapper);
   }

   const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
   cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.video-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.video-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="tcell">
      <div class="curtain-wrapper">
         <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
            <div class="curtain">
               <div class="container hide">
                  <div class="video-wrapper">
                     <div class="video-ratio-keeper">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="wrap hide">
                  <div class="video video-frame"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jacket" title="Play">
               <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                  <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                     M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
               </svg>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem seems to be the `const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;` line. The `nextElementSibling` does not have a `.video` child. You probably want `const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentNode;`. The API does not work in a sandboxed environment, so I do not know whether it behaves properly.

```js
const load = (function () {
   "use strict";

   function _load(tag) {
      return function (url) {
         return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            const element = document.createElement(tag);
            const parent = "body";
            const attr = "src";
            element.onload = function () {
               resolve(url);
            };
            element[attr] = url;
            document[parent].appendChild(element);
         });
      };
   }
   return {
      js: _load("script")
   };
}());

(function manageCover() {
   "use strict";

   function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
      document.querySelector(".curtain").classList.add("slide");
   }

   function hide(el) {
      el.classList.add("hide");
   }

   function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const thewrap = cover.parentNode.querySelector(".container");
      hide(cover);
      show(thewrap);

   }
   const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
   cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());


const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
   "use strict";

   function onPlayerReady(event) {
      const player = event.target;
      player.setVolume(100); // percent
   }
   let hasShuffled = false;

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
      const player = event.target;
      const shufflePlaylist = true;

      if (!hasShuffled) {
         player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
         player.playVideoAt(0);
         hasShuffled = true;
      }
   }

   function addVideo(video) {

      const playlist = "M7lc1UVf-VE";
      new YT.Player(video, {

         width: '640',
         height: '360',
         host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
         playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
            controls: 1,
            loop: 1,
            rel: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            fs: 0,
            disablekb: 1,
            playlist
         },
         events: {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
         }
      });
   }

   function init(opts) {
      load.js("https://www.youtube.com/player_api").then(function () {
         YT.ready(function () {
            addVideo(opts.video);
         });
      });
   }
   return {
      init
   };
}());

(function iife() {
   "use strict";

   function show(el) {
      el.classList.remove("hide");
   }

   function initPlayer(wrapper) {
      videoPlayer.init({
         video: wrapper.querySelector(".video")
      });
   }

   function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.parentNode;
      show(wrapper);
      initPlayer(wrapper);
   }

   const cover = document.querySelector(".jacket");
   cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.curtain-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.curtain {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.container {}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 8s;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);
}

.panel-right {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.video-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.video-ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 70px;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 30%;
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.wrap,
.jacket {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.wrap iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  height: calc(100% + 6px);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="tcell">
      <div class="curtain-wrapper">
         <div class="curtain-ratio-keeper">
            <div class="curtain">
               <div class="container hide">
                  <div class="video-wrapper">
                     <div class="video-ratio-keeper">
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-left"></div>
               <div class="wrap hide">
                  <div class="video video-frame"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jacket" title="Play">
               <svg class="play" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
                  <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                     M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
               </svg>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why .parentNode and not .parentElement?

Comment: Most of the time, they are exchangeable. In this case, I would prefer `parentNode`. In some cases, `parentElement` will return `null` and the script will fail, whereas `parentNode` will return the `document` and the script should still work.